# DefaultCredentialsError for running query in Jupyter notebook

Tags: google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter) Google cloud tutorial. Running codes in Jupyter notebook. Step 5 is fine and when I run step 7 I get this error:

```
DefaultCredentialsError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a1696640ccb4> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bigquery', '', 'SELECT\n    source_year AS year,\n    COUNT(is_male) AS birth_count\nFROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`\nGROUP BY year\nORDER BY year DESC\nLIMIT 15\n')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2379             with self.builtin_trap:
   2380                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2381                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2382             return result
   2383
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DefaultCredentialsError` means that the Application Default Credentials (ADC) that the client library is trying to use for authentication are not properly set.

You may have missed the step in the section **Setting up a local Jupyter environment** with the link for [Getting Started with Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).

In short, you need to set your default credentials by running a cell with the following code.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/key.json"
```

Where your path points to a valid service account key file.

You might also be able to set default credentials instead with the following in a cell if you have the gcloud sdk installed locally:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```